# Next.js prepending current path for nested dynamic routes in Link components

Tags: javascript, react-router, next.js, router

How would you go about dealing with nested dynamic routes and using Next.js Link component?

Say I have 2 file paths:

```
/pages/projects/index.js
```

```
<Link href={`/projects/${project.id}`} key={index}>
  <a>Project Name</a>
</Link>
```

This will take me to `localhost:3000/projects/some-id/`

and

```
/pages/projects/[pid]/index.js
```

This is where I'm having trouble figuring out how to prepend the path of `localhost:3000/projects/some-id/`

```
<Link href={`/${router.pathname}/apple`}>
  <a>Business name</a>
</Link>
```

If I use `router.pathname`, I get `/projects/[pid]/apple`, and its missing the domain name, if I use `router.asPath`, I get the correct path, but its still missing the domain. I don't know if this is the correct way, because i shouldn't be adding the domain name into Link's `href`.

Comment: So you want to have `projects` in your `router.pathname`, Am I get it corect?

Comment: It is a bit unclear. you have issue with `/pages/projects/index.js` and `/pages/projects/[pid]/index.js` or "missing the domain name" is the problem ?

Comment: @RyanLe hi, right because its nested in a dynamic route `[pid]`.  I wanted to be able to do this correctly, where I prepend the current URL within `/pages/projects/[pid]/index.js`, so then I can easily add the business name path after. From when you helped me last time, I wanted to be able to do the layout component as well, but I'm trying to figure out the correct pathname

Comment: @RGog well I'm tring to figure out how to deal with dynamic and nested routes, because whatever I'm doing is not getting the current route to prepend so I can do something like `/apple` at the end for the next page

Comment: Why don’t you put “project” and then your [pid] right after that?

Comment: @RyanLe well because I have a different folder, like `pages/projects/[pid]/[biz].js` as well. Is that what you're asking? Like have `[pid].js` instead of having a folder?

Comment: Oh. I see, so you want to have a nested dynamic routes? Meaning dynamic folder inside another one?

Comment: @RyanLe yup, that's what I currently have at the moment. So its like a project dashboard, and then there's multiple links within the project dashboard, that will take you to another page.

Comment: "if I use `router.asPath`, I get the correct path, but its still missing the domain" - How is missing the domain an issue? With `router.asPath` you'll get `/projects/some-id/apple` in your example, which is what you want, right? Either I'm missing something, or this needs more clarity on what you want to achieve.

Comment: with `<Link href={/${router.asPath}/apple}>`, it doesn't correctly link to `localhost:3000/projects/some-id/apple`, instead, it actually just links to `/projects/some-id/apple`, so without the domain, the site doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **For a nested dynamic route in Nextjs, you could set up your project like so:**

[image]

**Starting with a simple link in index.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Index</h2>
      <Link href="/projectA">
        <a>Project A</a>
      </Link>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**Once you are in `[projectId].js` use `useRouter` to get current param and append to your next route**

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Project() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { projectId } = router.query;
  return (
    <section>
      <Link href={`/${projectId}/2`}>
        <a>Project 2</a>
      </Link>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vristt?file=pages/%5BprojectId%5D/%5Bid%5D.js)**

Comment: Oh, that was simple. Why didn't I think of that? Using router.query... I think that was the key. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helps! Let me know if you want my help.